# Creating inline links to protocols with DoxyGen/Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

how can I create inline links to protocols in DoxyGen/Objective-C. When I reference a class, I  can just write the class name in camel case (e.g. NSObject) and DoxyGen creates a link to the class documentation.

How can I do the same for protocols? I tried `<NSObject>` (the way DoxyGen displays protocol names), but this did not work.

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work OK for me by just typing the name of the protocol (without angle brackets). Here's [an example](http://www.typhoonframework.org/docs/latest/api/interface_typhoon_patcher.html).

It won't work work for NSObject, unless you included those headers in your Doxyfile config. Doxygen only creates links to symbols it has indexed.